# Show only in progress records without finalized ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table CandidateInterview :

| CandidateID | InterviewID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 12 | Not yet |
| 100 | 13 | In progress |

```
CREATE TABLE CandidateInterview (CandidateID int, InterviewID int,
Status int)
INSERT INTO CandidateInterview VALUES 
(100     ,    12     ,     1),
(100      ,   13     ,     2),
(120     ,     9      ,    1)
```

I want to get only the candidates with only with Not Yet status
and not other ones

Answer (score 2):

**You can use window functions for this.**

Window functions are normally more efficient than correlated subqueries

```sql
SELECT
  CandidateID,
  InterviewID,
  Status
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      OtherStatus = COUNT(CASE WHEN Status > 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CandidateID)
    FROM CandidateInterview ci
) ci
WHERE OtherStatus = 0;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bf74/11)

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bf74/8)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE CandidateInterview (CandidateID int, InterviewID int,
Status int)
INSERT INTO CandidateInterview VALUES 
(100     ,    12     ,     1),
(100      ,   13     ,     2),
(120     ,     9      ,    1)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM CandidateInterview AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS 

(
  SELECT * FROM CandidateInterview AS B
  WHERE A.CandidateID=B.CandidateID
  AND Status >1
  
  
  )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3bf74/8/0)**:

```
| CandidateID | InterviewID | Status |
|-------------|-------------|--------|
|         120 |           9 |      1 |
```